# Function avoiding certain values in array

Tags: c

I'm currently writing a tic-tac-toe program using C for my CS class and I keep running into errors when running that stop me from placing my move in the positions [2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3], essentially only letting me place moves on the top row, and the left two columns of the second row. I'm assuming it has something to do with my `check_legal_option` function but I can't figure out what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <time.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <stdbool.h>

void clear_table(char table[3][3]);
void generate_player2_move(char table[3][3],int *row,int *col); 
int check_table_full(char table[3][3]);
int check_three_in_a_row(char table[3][3]);
void display_table(char table[3][3]);
int check_legal_option(char table[3][3],int moveRow,int moveCol);
void update_table(char table[3][3],int pRow,int pCol);

int main(void){ 
  char emptyTable[3][3];
  int row,col,cpuRow,cpuCol,full,three,legal;
  printf("This program plays the game of tic-tac-toe\n");
  clear_table(emptyTable);
  printf("\n");
  full = check_table_full(emptyTable);
  three = check_three_in_a_row(emptyTable);

  while(three == 0 && full == 0){

    display_table(emptyTable);
    printf("Player 1 enter your selection [row,col]: ");
    scanf("%d,%d",&row,&col);
    legal=check_legal_option(emptyTable,row,col);
    printf("%d",legal);
    while(legal!=1){
       printf("Player 1 enter your selection [row,col]: ");
      scanf("%d,%d",&row,&col);
      legal=check_legal_option(emptyTable,row,col);
    }
    update_table(emptyTable,row-1,col-1);
    generate_player2_move(emptyTable,&cpuRow,&cpuCol);
    full = check_table_full(emptyTable);
    three = check_three_in_a_row(emptyTable);
  }
  if(three == 1){
    printf("Congratulations, Player 1 wins!\n");
  }
  else if(three == 2){
    printf("Congratulations, Computer wins!\n");
  }
  else{
    printf("Game over, no player wins.\n");
  }
}

void clear_table(char table[3][3]){
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
      table[i][j] = '_';
    }
  }
}

void generate_player2_move(char table[3][3],int *row,int *col){
  srand (time(NULL));
  do{
    *row = rand()%3;
    *col = rand()%3;
    int legal = check_legal_option(table,*row,*col);
  }while(!check_legal_option(table,*row,*col));
  table[*row][*col] = 'O';
}

int check_table_full(char table[3][3]){
  if(table[0][0] == table[0][1] && table[0][1] == table[0][2] && table[0][2] == table[1][0] && table[1][0] == table[1][1] && table[1][1] == table[1][2] && table[1][2]
  == table[2][0] && table[2][0] == table[2][1] && table[2][1] == table[2][2] && table[0][0] != '_' && check_three_in_a_row(table) == 0){
return 3;
}
  return 0;
}

int check_three_in_a_row(char table[3][3]){
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){

    if(table[i][0] == table[i][1] && table[i][1] == table[i][2] && table[i][0] == 'X'){
      return 1;
    }
    if(table[i][0] == table[i][1] && table[i][1] == table[i][2] && table[i][0] == 'O'){
      return 2;
    }
  }
  for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
    //checks if player 1 or CPU gets vertical win
    if(table[0][j] == table[1][j] && table[1][j] == table[2][j] && 
table[0][j] == 'X'){
      return 1;
    }
    if(table[0][j] == table[1][j] && table[1][j] == table[2][j] && table[0][j] == 'O'){
      return 2;
    }
  }
  //checks if player 1 or CPU gets diagonal win one way
  if(table[0][0] == table[1][1] && table[1][1] == table[2][2] && table[0][0] == 'X'){
    return 1;
  }
  if(table[0][0] == table[1][1] && table[1][1] == table[2][2] && table[0][0] == 'O'){
    return 2;
  }
  //checks if player 1 or CPU gets diagonal win another way
  if(table[0][2] == table[1][1] && table[1][1] == table[2][0] && table[0][2] == 'X'){
    return 1;
  }
  if(table[0][2] == table[1][1] && table[1][1] == table[2][0] && table[0][2] == 'O'){
    return 2;
  }
  //if no one has three in a row, return 0
  return 0;
}

void display_table(char table[3][3]){
  printf("The current state of the game is:");
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    printf("\n");
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
      printf("%c ",table[i][j]);
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int check_legal_option(char table[3][3],int moveRow,int moveCol){
  if(table[moveCol][moveCol]=='_'){
    return 1;
  }
    return 0;
}

void update_table(char table[3][3],int pRow,int pCol){
  table[pRow][pCol] = 'X';
}
```

Comment: One obvious problem is that you aren't checking to see if the input row and column are within bounds.  It looks like the legal values are 0-2, but it someone enters 3 or higher, or a negative number, you will index out of bounds.

Comment: OT: `srand` should only be called once. Typically, the call to `srand` is near the beginning of `main`.

Answer (score 1):

The check_legal function uses movecol in both the columns and rows.